# CSV, Python: Using DictWriter correctly (ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames)

Tags: python, csv, unicode, dictionary

I'm having difficulties grasping the DictWriter in the csv module (Python 2.7). I have this (oh, and I'm using a unicodecsv library because I've read there are issues):

```
f = object_instance.return_a_dictionary.keys()
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = unicodecsv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=f)
    spamwriter.writerows(object_instance.return_a_dictionary)
```

So  I pass in my object instance. f is:

```
[u'n6s2f0e1', u'n1s0f0e0', u'n2s0f0e1', u'n3s1f0e0', u'n5s2f0e0', u'n4s1f0e1']
```

object_instance.return_a_dictionary is:

```
{u'n6s2f0e1': u'stuff', u'n1s0f0e0': u'stuff', u'n2s0f0e1': u'stuff', u'n3s1f0e0': u'stuff', u'n5s2f0e0': u'stuff', u'n4s1f0e1': u'stuff'}
```

So really I want a first row:

```
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
```

I'm under the impression that writerow goes through the provided dictionary, calls the keyname of the provided dict with the dictwriter fieldnames provided, and outputs the value.

Instead I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 153, in writerows
rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
>>> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
", ".join(wrong_fields))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: n, 6, s, 2, f, 0, e, 1
```

I just don't understand this at this point. It does this with both the regular Python csv library and a unicode csv library I've found. Can anyone explain what the issue is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want `writerow` not `writerows`.

The former takes a single argument, which is the row to be written. The latter takes an iterable of rows. You are calling `writerows` with a dictionary, which tries to iterate over the dictionary and write each entry. Since iterating over dicts gives their keys, this is the same as calling `writerow(n6s2f0e1)` which (obviously) fails with the error you see.

Comment: I just came to notate my question with this, one tiny misunderstood 's', but at least I'll be able to differentiate in the future.

Comment: FYI the way I worked it out was that it was interpreting your fields as n, 6, ... -- which means that it's iterating over the string `"n6s2f0e1"` as a row instead of as a key. From there the explanation is pretty easy.

Comment: I knew it was pulling it apart for some reason, but the first I've actually started to use the csv module, so I'm clueless.