# Why Field names are sliced and raise error in python csv writing

Tags: csv, selenium, python-2.6

During practicing selenium i failed to write a dictionary into csv.I have searched the problem solution like [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367732/csv-python-using-dictwriter-correctly-valueerror-dict-contains-fields-not-in) but it did not help me. My problem is when i want to write a python dictionary into csv file using dictwriter i reach at exception i.e.

> ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: u'S', u'k', u'u'

but the field name is

> Sku

Why it is sliced and gives me queer exception but i supplied proper filednames in the dictwriter.

My experimenting code. is-

```
import os,sys,bs4,random,codecs,requests
import unicodecsv as csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from contextlib import contextmanager
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



current_file =  sys.argv[0]
link_dir = os.path.dirname(current_file)
link_path = os.path.join(link_dir,'lnks.txt')

Image_folder = os.path.join(link_dir,"images")+"\\"

urls = [line.strip() for line in open(link_path, 'r')]
urls = list(set(urls))
url = urls[0]



driver = webdriver.Firefox()#Chrome()##chromedriver)##

base_url = 'http://www.hotleathers.com'

Header = [u'Url',u'Name',u'Sku',u'Price',u'Color',u'Size']
#def get_data(url):
#try:
print "Scraping : %s"%url
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
detpage_lnks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:5px']/a")
detpage_lnks = map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('href'),detpage_lnks)
for i in detpage_lnks:
    Data = []
    #try:
    driver.get(i)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    Name_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table [@class='showproductpage']/tbody/tr/td/h1").text
    Sku_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table[@cellspacing = '0'])[3]//td[@style='padding-left:5px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;']").text
    image_name = Sku_v+".jpg"
    image_url = "http://www.hotleathers.com/Assets/ProductImages/large/"+image_name
    res = requests.get(image_url)
    if res.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        out = open(Image_folder+image_name,'wb')
        out.write(res.content)        
    Price_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//table[@cellspacing = '0'])[3]//tr)[2]//span").text
    Color=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//table[@class='buyProductForm'])//tr[2]/td/select/option")
    Color_v = '"'+':'.join([i.text for i in Color[1:]])+'"'
    Size=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//table[@class='buyProductForm'])//tr[3]/td/select/option")
    Size_v = '"'+':'.join([i.text for i in Size[1:]])+'"'
    temp = [driver.current_url,Name_v,Sku_v,Price_v,Color_v,Size_v]
    Data.append(zip(Header,temp))
    Data = [item for sublst in Data for item in sublst]
    my_dict = dict(Data)
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(link_dir,"Image_info.csv"),'wb',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # Using dictionary keys as fieldnames for the CSV file header
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=",", fieldnames=Header,lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        for d in my_dict:
            writer.writerow(d)             

driver.close()
```

**I tried both unicodecsv and csv but with no success.**

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries i found solution as below-
I did not understand that writerow expects a dictionary!

```
import os,sys,bs4,random,codecs,requests
import unicodecsv as csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from contextlib import contextmanager
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import staleness_of
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



current_file =  sys.argv[0]
link_dir = os.path.dirname(current_file)
link_path = os.path.join(link_dir,'lnks.txt')

Image_folder = os.path.join(link_dir,"images")+"\\"

urls = [line.strip() for line in open(link_path, 'r')]
urls = list(set(urls))
url = urls[0]



driver = webdriver.Firefox()#Chrome()##chromedriver)##

base_url = 'http://www.hotleathers.com'

Header = [u'Url',u'Name',u'Sku',u'Price',u'Color',u'Size']
#def get_data(url):
#try:
print "Scraping : %s"%url
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
detpage_lnks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:5px']/a")
detpage_lnks = map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('href'),detpage_lnks)
for i in detpage_lnks:
    Data = []
    #try:
    driver.get(i)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    Name_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table [@class='showproductpage']/tbody/tr/td/h1").text
    Sku_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table[@cellspacing = '0'])[3]//td[@style='padding-left:5px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;']").text
    image_name = Sku_v+".jpg"
    image_url = "http://www.hotleathers.com/Assets/ProductImages/large/"+image_name
    res = requests.get(image_url)
    if res.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        out = open(Image_folder+image_name,'wb')
        out.write(res.content)        
    Price_v=driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//table[@cellspacing = '0'])[3]//tr)[2]//span").text
    Color=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//table[@class='buyProductForm'])//tr[2]/td/select/option")
    Color_v = '"'+':'.join([i.text for i in Color[1:]])+'"'
    Size=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//table[@class='buyProductForm'])//tr[3]/td/select/option")
    Size_v = '"'+':'.join([i.text for i in Size[1:]])+'"'
    temp = [driver.current_url,Name_v,Sku_v,Price_v,Color_v,Size_v]
    Data.append(zip(Header,temp))
    Data = [item for sublst in Data for item in sublst]
    my_dict = dict(Data)
    with codecs.open(os.path.join(link_dir,"Image_info.csv"),'ab',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # Using dictionary keys as fieldnames for the CSV file header
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=my_dict.keys())
        writer.writerow(my_dict)             

driver.close()
```